# Laravel eloquent model: return only column names

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I have a basic eloquent model. When i fetch a model using the query builder like:

```
$User = User::whereUser_login('test')->first();
```

And then i use

```
$User->toArray();
```

I am getting the array with the same data twice. First the data is set to a numeric key and then to the column name like:

```
"0": 1037,
"1": "test",
"2": "$P$B.k90STXa.ugL6KjdYhPqO/WTYJRjU/",
"ID": test,
"user_login": "test"
```

I want only the column name associations. The issue is that i have a $hidden attribute inside the model where i am hiding the password column and it works ok since its not returning the password column but i still have the 2 key where the password is set.

Thanks.

Comment: check that the `fetch` setting in the `config/database.php` is set to `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`. `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the PDO **[fetch style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)** is currently set to `FETCH_BOTH`

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column
>   name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

Ensure that the `fetch` setting is in your apps `config/database.php` and is set to `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`.

```
<?php

return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
...
]
```